# Why isn't this extracting the price correctly? Every price comes out to 0? Also it said 'payment' was being referenced before it was defined?

Tags: python

```
# Sample line of text from file (Ford,F150,55000;)    
filename = 'carPrice.txt'

def main():

    all_prices= {}

    try:
        with open(filename) as fh:
            for line in fh:
                make, model, price = line.strip().split(',')
                all_prices[(make,model)]=price.strip()

        income = float(input("Enter your monthly income amount:"))
        print("Your monthly income amount is",income,)
        make = input("Enter Make of the car:")
        print("You selected a",make,)
        model = input("Enter Model of the car:")
        print("You selected a",model,)
        price_value=0
        for x in price:
            if x == (make,model):
                price_value=price[x]
        print("The price of that car is",price_value,)
        payment = (price_value* 0.80)/60
        print("The monthly payment is",payment,)

        if (payment < 0.11*income):
            print("The monthly payment of",payment,"= Acceptable Risk")
            return "Acceptable"
        else:
            print("The monthly payment of",payment,"= Unacceptable Risk")
            return "Unacceptable"

    # Exception added to enable troubleshooting of errors on lines
    except OSError as e:
        print(e.errno)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal).

Answer (score 1):

With respect, the code seems to be a bit all over the place, specifically in regards to price. If this is an exact copy of your code I think you may have lost track of what 'price' actually is.

For example here:

```
for x in price:
    if x == (make,model):
        price_value=price[x]
```

However, `price` here is a `string` value you pulled from the file e.g. £100. You're then iterating over that `£, 1, 0, 0` and checking it against the make and model.

Finally you make the `price_value` an index of this string e.g.

```
price[x]  # could be price["£"]
```

This would then cause an exception.

I'd go through your code again and look to make sure you're referencing `price`, `price_value` and `all_prices` where you actually want them